# When I run my React Native app in my device without connecting on the pc via cable, it show the app state 2 month ago

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

It still happening since 2 month ago. When I execute "react-native run-android" it load the newest app, what I have changed on code. But since I disconnect the cable of the device and I try to open the application is shown the application since 2 month ago more or less.(I am debugging directly with my phone) I don't know why it happens. I have thought could be something about the cache but it hide of my knowledge. I tried to uninstall the application and open the project with Android Studio and play it (it suppose that it install the app forever in the device, or at least is what I was think)  and while the cable is connected to my device, nothing weird happened, just the newest state of my app is played as it should be. But again, with the application installed in my phone by Android Studio, when i disconnect the cable of my phone and rerun the app, loads the older app. I am becoming crazy, I need help for this weird problem. 
Thanks!! 
Note: In iPhone does not happen , but i was happen the first times when the error appeared the first time in the iPhone emulator.
Additional information:React-Native version: 0.49.3

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue before, here is some advices to get rid of it

- uninstall the app before re-install
- make sure to uninstall for all users if you have multiple accounts on
  your device (Android) `Settings -> Apps -> {your app} -> more -> uninstall for all users`
- uncheck Automatic restore (Android) `Settings -> Backup & reset -> Automatic restore`

Comment: Ooook, I am going to explain what happened when I did what you said. First of all, worked, thanks you very much. BUT I found incoherent things that are forcing me to think that some cache problem is happening yet.
The first I did was the steps you wrote here. After this I thought, what should I test first, the react-native run-android command or just open the project with Android Studio and run it? Due to I had working a long time with Android I opened it with Android Studio first. ++++

Comment: ++++When I ran the App it opened the older version. Then I uninstalled the App and replicated the same of your steps again. Next I ran the react-native run-android command and it worked fine. After I disconnected the cable and rerun the app and worked without the cable in the latest version. For ensure myself, I rebooted my device and I ran again the app. All its ok. But I still asking myself what happen with Android Studio, why it still executing the older version? ++++

Comment: ++++ And weirdest when 30 min ago I ran the App with Android Studio and it installed the latest version. Should be maybe that do I have the compile older version in anywhere? Anyway, it worked for me so, thanks so much!!!!!!!
Sorry my english!

Comment: The error still happening... After 1 hour more or less it became to the older version. I am going to kill my self T_T

Answer (score 0):

**Uninstall** your older app from android device and re-install it again and check it.